# Mount a Single SPA MFE to DOM of a NON Single SPA application

Tags: reactjs, single-spa, single-spa-react

I have a React application that is quite mature which has been developed using React version 16.14.0. Recently, there has come a need to Plugin some of the MFEs developed using Single SPA to this application.
As I have tried out converting the current application to Single SPA seems to be quite far fetched given the breaking changes that the application has to go through. Therefore, I would like to know whether it is possible to mount those MFEs as DOM elements into my current application and interact them as React components.
I would like to know the feasibility of such approach and any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You need to provide more details or link to repos for more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, strictly speaking it is possible to mount MFE's in your existing project.  The single-spa team will tell you to create a root config project, then mount your current application as MFE, and in turn, make your MFE mount the others.

While perfectly OK route, I dislike it because it is not as simple.  Furthermore, root config projects use SystemJS modules and not native ES Modules.  If you want ES modules, you'll have to reconfigure.

So, for the record:  Seriously consider going the path recommended.

### My Answer

Now, *personally* speaking, I prefer to do exactly what you say you want to do:  Just mount stuff in my existing project.

To do this, in a nutshell:

1. Install single-spa.
2. Decide where to put the calls to `registerApplication()` and `start()` in your current project.
3. Obtain URL's for your micro-frontends and program them when register the applications.  Make sure you use the correct `import()` function according to the type of module in use (`System.import()` for SystemJS modules, or `import()` for native ES modules).
4. Add markup (empty `<div>` elements, most of the time) in the places where the MFE's will be mounted.  They require the `id` attribute set to `single-spa-application:<mfe Name>`, where `<mfe Name>` is the name given to the MFE in the call to `registerApplication()`.

Optionally, you could assign *bare specifiers* (or aliases) to the URL's of the MFE's and also include an import map in your current application's index page.  This is another conversation, so I'll just stop here.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed response and thank you for providing me a path in achieving this. I would like to clarify regarding the step 2. Since, my application is a React application should the registerApplication() and start() happen before ReactDOM.render() function?

Comment: It doesn't have to happen before.  If you read single-spa's documentation, you should realize that it is framework agnostic.  Simply:  MFE's won't load unless they are registered and single-spa is started.  That's it.  To give you an example, some people like calling start() only after the user authenticates to prevent showing unauthorized things.

Comment: Thanks to your valuable guideline now I am being able to integrate the MFE to my React application. Just one glitch I am observing is when the div with the corresponding id attribute is not available Single SPA seems to be appending the MFE at the bottom of the DOM. Is there a way that I can mount the application to the div only when the MFE should be available and remove it when it should be removed?

Comment: Don't extend questions with more questions.  Make a new question.  Yes, it is how single-spa does it.  Yes, you could explore single-spa's events so you proactively include the DIV only when the MFE is about to mount.